# Conv1DTranspose to specific length

Tags: tensorflow, keras, transpose, convolution, conv-neural-network

I am building a GAN and faced with a silly question.
My features are 1D and [174,1] as shape, while the discriminator works I am having some issues to upsample my latent variable to 174,1 in the generator.
I modified some code for mnist which was using conv2dtranspose so there might be something directly for 1d signals out there.

```
z_size = 100
output_size=(174, 1)
n_filters=128
n_blocks=2
size_factor = 2**n_blocks
hidden_size = (output_size[0]//size_factor)
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Input(shape=z_size,))
model.add(Dense(units=n_filters*hidden_size))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU())
model.add(Reshape((hidden_size, n_filters)))
# now we upsample the feature space to
model.add(Conv1DTranspose(filters=n_filters,
                          kernel_size=4,
                          strides=1,
                          padding='same',
                          use_bias=False
                          ))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(LeakyReLU())

nf = n_filters
for i in range(n_blocks):
    nf = nf // 2
    model.add(Conv1DTranspose(filters=nf,
                              kernel_size=5,
                              strides=2,
                              padding='same',
                              use_bias=False
                              ))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(LeakyReLU())

model.add(Conv1DTranspose(filters=output_size[1],
                          kernel_size=5,
                          strides=1,
                          padding='same',
                          use_bias=False,
                          activation='tanh')
                          )
model.summary()
```

but then the dimensions are just off.

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense (Dense)                (None, 5504)              555904    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 5504)              22016     
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu (LeakyReLU)      (None, 5504)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 43, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_transpose (Conv1DTran (None, 43, 128)           65536     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 43, 128)           512       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_1 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 43, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_transpose_1 (Conv1DTr (None, 86, 64)            40960     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 86, 64)            256       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_2 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 86, 64)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_transpose_2 (Conv1DTr (None, 172, 32)           10240     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 172, 32)           128       
_________________________________________________________________
leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)    (None, 172, 32)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_transpose_3 (Conv1DTr (None, 172, 1)            160       
=================================================================
Total params: 695,712
Trainable params: 684,256
Non-trainable params: 11,456
 _________________________________________________________________
```

This originates from the hidden_size = (output_size[0]//size_factor) which is 174//4 -> 43.5 rounded to 43 hence when upsampled goes to 172.
So should I manually calculate the correct size? or do only one upsampling?